How do you manually install plugins for Neovim on Windows without a plugin manager, and without WSL or similar?
I'm trying to configure a vim plugin on neovim on Windows 10. I specifically don't want to use WSL or similar. I'm proficient with vi as an editor but have never used vim or neovim with plugins.
I'm trying to avoid installing a plugin manager just to install two specific plugins I'm interested in, and also because it shouldn't be necessary.
The plugin I'm trying to use as an example is Markdown Drawer. I've tried reading all kinds of guides on where to place the files, in sub subdirectory of C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\nvim\
No matter what I do, I can't get :MarkDrawer to work, which per the README should start the plugin. Where is the correct location to install a vim plugin for neovim on Windows without a plugin manager or WSL?

You don't have to delete your question (unless you want to), you can also self-answer. Please don't put an answer in the question, this won't help future readers. For problems with your account, you can reach out to a moderator (I flagged your question so I would expect one of them to get in touch with you).

Deleting a useful question is not really in the spirit of how this site operates. I’m not sure how you would edit the question without being signed in to the same account with posted it, at which point you should be able to delete if you want. Again, though, I urge you to reconsider: leaving the question and posting an answer helps more people in the long run.
